# Sync iCal in Iphone appilication

Tags: iphone

Cam we sync iCal in Iphone application?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no framework to access the iPhone OS calendar currently.

Answer (score 2):

We can sync ical in iphone application. iOS 4.0 and next  provide the api to access ical events. I also have a sample code for this

Comment: can you provide link for those samples